# Multiple polylines from XML

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-polyline

I want to display multiple polylines from an XML file:

```
<lines>
    <line>
        <linePoint lat="47.608940" lng="-122.340141"/>
        <linePoint lat="47.613590" lng="-122.344391"/>
        <linePoint lat="47.624561" lng="-122.356445"/>
    </line>
    <line>
        <linePoint lat="47.616600" lng="-122.344491"/>
        <linePoint lat="47.627661" lng="-122.356545"/>
    </line>
</lines>
```

I believe that the script should iterate twice - the outer loop going through `line` elements and the inner loop going through `linePoint` elements within each `line`.

But it seems that my script dumps all 5 `linePoint` into a single polyline instead of creating 2 polylines.

```js
downloadUrl("createXML.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var line = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("line");
    // Read each line
    for (var a = 0; a < line.length; a++) {
        var linePoint = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("linePoint");
        var path = [];
        // Read markers on each line
        for (var i = 0; i < linePoint.length; i++) {
            var lat = parseFloat(linePoint[i].getAttribute("lat"));
            var lng = parseFloat(linePoint[i].getAttribute("lng"));
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
            path.push(point);
        }

        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: path
        });
        polyline.setMap(map);
    }
});
```

Can someone please point out what I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is because you just extract `all` `<linePoint>`'s in one chunk by `getElementsByTagName("linePoint")` (elements in plural). Iterate over `<line>`'s and for each `<line>` iterate over its `<linePoint>`'s :

```js
function showPolyLines() {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xml = parser.parseFromString(responseXML, "application/xml");
  var line = xml.querySelectorAll("line");

  for (var l = 0; l < line.length; l++) {
    var path = [],
        linePoints = line[l].querySelectorAll('linePoint');

    for (var p = 0; p < linePoints.length; p++) {
      var linePoint = linePoints[p],
        lat = parseFloat(linePoint.getAttribute("lat")),
        lng = parseFloat(linePoint.getAttribute("lng")),
        point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

      path.push(point);
    }
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: path,

      //just to be sure the lines actually is shown on the map :) 
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });
    polyline.setMap(map);
  }
}
```

I am using a [**DOMParser**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to substitute `xml.documentElement` because I dont have a real `responseXML` in my fiddle test, but they are practically the same.

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9sqastj1/**